# Cucumber doesn't find steps definition in other module

Tags: cucumber-java

A have two separate java modules.

Module A specifies a class with Cucumber step definitions:

```
package de.company.difin.testclient;

public class StepDefinitions {
...
}
```

Module B has the Tests contained in feature files which are executed with JUnit 5:

```
package de.company.difin.testclient;

...

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "classpath:testsuite/",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/reports/test-report.html", "json:target/reports/test-report.json"},
    glue = {"de.company.difin.testclient.StepDefinitions"},
)
public class TestClientTest
{
}
```

All tests are failing with an
*io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException*
i.e the step definition couldn't be found.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: glue should be a package name, not a class name.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje,
but if I write 

`glue = {"de.company.difin.testclient"}`

it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Mmh. That means you also have another problem. Does everything work if you put the steps in the same module as the test?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje, yes, then everything works fine. The other module actually is not within a multi module maven project but it is taken by Nexus. But I don't know if this is relevant

Comment: You are using a split package. The package `de.company.difin.testclient` is in both modules. This may confuse things. Try a different package for one of them.

Comment: And if that doesn't work you'd have to create an MCVE and create a bug report. How your modules are constructed may be of importance too.